# API design: Better to wrap IKVM java.util.Set in a .NET 4 ISet?

Tags: java, .net, api-design, ikvm

I'm exposing a Java library I wrote to .NET using [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), which compiles Java bytecode to CLR bytecode. This works great, and my question has to do with API design. My API is very simple and small. The method calls return an object which implements java.util.Set. My question is, from the point of view of a .NET developer, which of the following is more developer-friendly:

1. To return this Java object directly to the developer, in which case the developer must import the IKVM Core and Util libraries into their code, OR
2. To try to wrap the returned Java object it in a .NET-friendly interface? The only Set interface standard to .NET is [ISet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx), which only exists in .NET 4.

In general, I think it would be better to wrap the returned object in an interface that .NET developers expect to see, which would indicate that it's better to design my public API to return an ISet. However, I also think it would be good to allow my application to run on earlier versions of .NET, which is impossible if the API relies on ISet. If I don't use ISet, then it seems any Set interface would be acceptable, including java.util.Set.

I'd appreciate any guidance anyone can offer.

Comment: I'm not too familar with Java, but it appears that the .NET equivalent would be [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), introduced in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Good idea, but HashSet is a class, not an interface. I don't want the overhead of converting the Java class to a .NET class every time the method is called. I just want to wrap the Java object in a familiar .NET interface, if that's more appropriate.